# Sum distances between points in list using Java8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of points (x,y) and I want to sum the distances between them. In *old* Java I would do it like this:

```
List<Point> points = ...
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
    sum += PointUtil.distance(points.get(i), points.get(i + 1));
}
return sum;
```

Now the question is: can I do the same code using `points.stream(). ...`?

Comment: In "old" Java, you should use the `Iterator` with a reference to the previous element, as `get` can have bad performances depending on the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the first thing I could think of:

```
sum = IntStream.range(0,points.size()-1)
               .mapToLong(i -> PointUtil.distance(points.get(i), points.get(i + 1)))
               .sum();
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can use `IntStream`, in order to have indexing:

```
long sum = IntStream.range(0, points.size() - 1)
                    .mapToLong(i -> PointUtil.distance(points.get(i), points.get(i + 1)))
                    .sum();
```